# ideal btrfs storage scheme to incorporate external USB HDD as backup media

Tags: backup, btrfs

Is there a way to leverage btrfs's advanced features (COW, snapshots, etc.) to continuously backup/mirror my main storage volume to an external USB HDD?

Comment: do `man btrfs-send` and `man btrfs-receive` you might also want to look at quotas and compression - though, in honesty if you use send/receive you can just pipe the i/o through a compression tool instream as you do.

Comment: @mikeserv - I think you have put me on the right track. Thanks. Now I need to find a send/receive tutorial. The man pages are not enough. I believe I also need to investigate snapper and buttersink (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/buttersink/0.5)

Comment: Well, the best way is to experiment - but maybe I'll write something for you too. In any case - with `btrfs` you can always create a subvolume at any time - do anything you like there - and then destroy it atomically. So you should have no fear if you do something like for any kind of experimentation there. Oh, and I can't say I agree with you about those helper scripts, but that's probably just a difference in style - I'm sure they're fine.

Comment: @mikeserv - thanks and I look forward to any suggestions or tutorials you come up with. I have been using btrfs for several years and it has been great. But I have not tapped into any of its advanced features. I think all the warnings about it not being ready for serious use made me hesitant to explore anything other than the basic functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [btrfs Wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Incremental_Backup) lists several Incremental Backup tools that are suitable in response to this question.

[btrbk](https://digint.ch/btrbk/) is the one I am currently using and it meets most of the requirements mentioned in the question.

I say "most" because the question was not clear regarding the differences between snapshots and a true versioning file system (which btrfs is not). But the question is specific to btrfs and the best btrfs solution is frequent snapshots together with a tool that automates the creating the snapshots, send-receive transfers and pruning the snapshot timeline.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you're looking to create a mirror (or close enough to one) of your system hard drive, so as to utilize the mirror in the event of say a disk failure.

To me this looks like a case for RAID 1. This can be done with either BTRFS or MDADM. In either case when connecting the external drive back to the system, you'll need to ensure it is seen as the "slave." Since more recent writes would have likely occurred on the system, this should be the case. In btrfs one could then run a scrub operation (btrfs-scrub).

If you want to use btrfs-send and btrfs-receive, see http://marc.merlins.org/perso/btrfs/post_2014-03-22_Btrfs-Tips_-Doing-Fast-Incremental-Backups-With-Btrfs-Send-and-Receive.html

Regarding snapshots, snapshots can not be made across filesystems. So a snapshot must be created on the same filesystem as the btrfs subvolume for which the snapshot is to be made. That is where send/receive come into play as described in the reference previously mentioned.

Alternatively you could use fssync, though granted you would be ssh'ing into the localhost. fssync is reported from the man page to work well with btrfs.

If you have another system, you might consider using DRBD in single-primary mode. Though you may be able to get this to work with both drives on a single system, I've seen reports that indicate this does not work.

Note that RAID, synchronization, and replication is considered by many not a suitable substitute for a backup system.

Comment: I think RAID1 with an external USB drive will slow my system down too much (so I've been told). Maybe the send/receive script with hourly snapshots is about as close as I can get to the ideal...

Comment: @MountainX: RAID1 should be easy enough to test. Are you limited to USB? Could you use eSATA or a SATA bay case that can be "ejected," a 3.5in SATA hard drive hot-swap bay. If limited to USB, is it USB 2 or 3?

Comment: RAID1 is not an appropriate backup solution. (That's true without regard to speed issues.) That is why I did not accept this answer.